# Pixastic Blur not working - variable issue?

Tags: jquery, image, blur, pixastic

So I want to try the [Pixastic blur fast method](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blurfast/) to blur an image.
The code they supply in the documentation is the following:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "blurfast", {amount:0.5});
}
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = "myimage.jpg";
```

But when I try it on my page like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myImg = new Image();
    myImg.onload = function() {
        Pixastic.process(myImg, "blurfast", {amount:0.5});
    }
    document.body.appendChild(myImg);
    myImg.src = "../img/theImage.jpg";
});
```

It simply does nothing.

I also tried to call it like this, also without any result:

```
var img = new Image();
$(".div img").load(function(){
    Pixastic.process(img, "blurfast", {amount:0.5});
});
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = "../img/theImage.jpg";
```

It does not even throw an error!

I tried to understand what is happening: In `img`, a new image is created. As soon as the image in `.div` has loaded, Pixastic fires and adds the blur effect to the newly created image. Now, the image is applied as a child and gets a `src` attribute.

As you probably notice, I have some logical errors in there, but I can't get this clear. I believe that in the above code, `img` is not always the same. Sometimes it's the variable, sometimes it has to be the actual image from the `img`-tag. Is this true? Or do you see any other thing that strikes you? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it!
I need to call it through the jQuery method for some reason. Like:

```
$(".div img").pixastic("blurfast", {amount:0.5});
```