# Image editing with a slider and Pixastic library

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, coffeescript, pixastic

I'm trying to edit an image using the [Pixastic js library](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/) so that the image is automatically blurred to a certain value when the user moves a JqueryUI slider. I've already gotten this to work using a slider to adjust the opacity CSS value the image using this coffeescript:

```
#This works
$('.sliderop').slider
    min: 0
    max: 1
    value: 1
    step: 0.01
    range: "min"
    slide: (event, ui) ->
        $("#img_16").css('opacity', ui.value)
```

But when I try to do basically the same thing using the Pixastic library, no dice:

```
#This doesn't
$('.sliderbl').slider
    min: 0
    max: 5
    value: 0.5
    step: 0.1
    range: "min"
    slide: (event, ui) ->
        Pixastic.process($("#img_16"), "blurfast", { amount: ui.value})
```

The weird thing with this code is that it "freezes" the slider--when I load the page the slider stays stuck on the default value of "0.5" and can't be moved (but if I comment out the `Pixastic.process($("#img_16"), "blurfast", { amount: ui.value})` code, it moves normally again).

Is this a problem with my code or with the way I'm using the Pixastic library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using jquery version of Pixastic library. If you download Pixastic library without jquery plugins, then the previous code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found an answer on another question [Pixastic Blur not working - variable issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837215/pixastic-blur-not-working-variable-issue)

The code works when changed to:

```
$('.sliderbl').slider
    min: 0
    max: 5
    value: 0.5
    step: 0.1
    range: "min"
    slide: (event, ui) ->
        $("#img_16").pixastic("blurfast", {amount:ui.value})
```

Still, I'm curious why this works and the other code doesn't. On another page (not using a slider in this way) that Pixastic call worked fine.